# Data Annotation - Dynamic assignment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class "SampleDTO.cs" and i would like assign data annanatoation attributes during run time.

For an example

SampleDTO.cs
{

```
public string Name
{
    get;set;

}
```

}

I need to force, required field validation, minimum or maximum field validation based on condition. I have been searching for a forum and couldnt get any solution..

My expection is,

```
if(some condition1)
{
    check SampleDTO.Name property for Required field validator check.
}
else if(some condition2)
{
    check SampleDTO.Name property for minimum and maximum length check.
}
else{
    someother check.
}
```

(This can be done easily, by decorating the required, min/max length attribute on the SampleDTO.cs class. I am expecting this to implement it dynamically instead of static assignment.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the condition linked to the DTO itself, or is it external to the DTO? Put another way, can you give an example condition?

Comment: Seems like there is a better way to go about what you want, but this may be possible, depending on exactly what you need, by customizing DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088274/possible-to-change-data-annotations-during-runtime-asp-net-mvcs-range-requ